# Quicker than quick

Tags: riddle, word

> Quicker than quick, that's what they say,
> Add an E and thirds go away,
> Lose my first and a test comes to play,
> What am I? Can you solve and convey?

Good luck!

Hint:

> Keep me the same, you'll be hungry a day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are

> FAST

Quicker than quick, that's what they say

> Fast is a synonym of quick, perhaps even very quick

Add an E and thirds go away

> Feast: Not sure entirely, but perhaps during a feast you don't follow the [rule of thirds?](https://betterbodychemistry.com/insulin/genes-line-plate-rule-thirds/)

Lose my first and a test comes to play

> AST scrambled = SAT

Hint:

> If you fast, you don't eat and will be hungry!

Comment: For the "Add an E and thirds go away" clue, if you add an E, you get "feast", and taking away the third letter gives you "fat". Good job!

Answer (score 4):

Are you a

> **RACE**

Quicker than quick, that's what they say,

> The quicker than quick will win the race.

Add an E and thirds go away,

> I see a little play here. Add an E and Third S - Go away
>  Add an ERACE, Put third letter as S - Gives *ERASE* i.e. Go away

Lose my first and a test comes to play,

> [ACE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addenbrooke%27s_Cognitive_Examination) test

Comment: That's a good guess, but not quite correct. I added a hint with an additional clue.